# WP_Query creating extra blank results

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written the following function for my Wordpress site:

```
add_shortcode('publish_party', 'party_contact_suppliers');

function party_contact_suppliers(){
    $alerts = new WP_Query (array (
        'post_type'    => 'alert',
        'post_status' => 'publish'));
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($alerts as $alert) {
        echo '<li>'.$alert->ID.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}
```

I have two published alerts. However this is the output I am getting:

1. 
2. 
3. 
4. 
5. 
6. 
7. 
8. 
9. 
10. 
11. 600
12. 
13. 
14. 
15. 
16. 
17. 
18. 
19. 
20. 
21. 
22. 
23. 
24. 
25. 
26. 
27. 
28. 
29. 
30. 
31. 
32. 
33. 
34. 
35. 
36. 
37. 
38. 
39. 
40. 
41. 
42. 
43. 
44. 

I have gone into phpMyAdmin to check, and there are only 3 alerts in the database, two of which have a status of 'publish'. They are post ID 600 and post ID 599.

I was expecting to see two items, why are there 44, and only one ID showing?

Comment: Guess that is because you are foreaching directly over the WP_Query object, which is not the right way to do this. Go read the class documentation in the WP codex, it has examples on how to do this properly. (Does not necessarily need the loop syntaxes described there, the `$posts` property holds an _actual_ array that you can iterate over with foreach.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$alert` object that you return contains the postdata as a property, which you are missing. Which means that you should be trying to access it like `$alert->post->ID;` instead of `$alert->ID;`

It's also generally a better idea to follow the example loop that the [WP_Query docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) show by using a `while` loop and getting the postdata (`the_post()`) inside the loop, and then following that with a `wp_reset_postdata()`. You can then also access the ID by using the `get_the_ID()` function instead.

```
add_shortcode('publish_party', 'party_contact_suppliers');
function party_contact_suppliers(){
    $alerts = new WP_Query (array (
        'post_type'    => 'alert',
        'post_status' => 'publish'));
    echo '<ol>';
    while($alerts->have_posts()) {
        $alerts->the_post();
        echo '<li>'.get_the_ID().'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ol>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Frits, but now I'm getting no output at all?

Comment: @Dinoboy ah - my fault - I had a typo. Have edited to fix it, but `$alert->the_post()` needed to be `$alerts->the_post()`

Comment: Whoohooo! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
    add_shortcode('publish_party', 'party_contact_suppliers');

    function party_contact_suppliers(){
        $alerts = new WP_Query (array (
            'post_type'    => 'alert',
            'post_status' => array('publish')
            )
        );
        if ($alerts->have_posts()) {
            echo "<ol>";
            while ($alerts->have_posts()) : $alerts->the_post();
                echo '<li>'.get_the_ID().'<li>';
            endwhile;
            echo "</ol>";
        }
    }
```